# Missing $, Extra } and Extra } needed

Tags: math-mode, errors

Here is a MNWE including the following definition with a list but the last item is throwing up problems as described in the title and also the indent of the last bullet isn't indented as the others are;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newenvironment{definition}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[Two-dimensional curves]
  {It is called a simple arc of a curve, the set $C$ of points $M(x,y) \in \R ^2 $
    (two-dimensional Euclidean space) satisfying one of the following equivalent equations;}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{
      $ y=f(x), \text{ where } a,b \in \R \text{ and are also fixed} \text{,}$
    }
    \item{
      $ F(x,y)=0, \text{ } a_1 \leq x \leq a_2,\text{ }b_1 \leq y \leq b_2 \text{ where, } a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \R \text{,}$
    }
    \item{
      $
      \left\{\begin{array}{cll}
        x=g(t)\\
        y=h(t)
      \end{array}\right. \text{, where c_1<t< c_2} \text{ and } c_1,c_2 \in \R
      \text{.}$
    }
  \end{itemize}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide your code as a complete document which we can try to compile to reproduce the error. Please also give the exact text of the error message.

Comment: @cfr i can but its now at about 5 pages long?

Comment: No not your real document. Make your minimal example complete. I've tried to patch it together, but I can't reproduce the error because I get a different error first. You probably need more preamble. But you also need less preamble: only include packages required to reproduce the error.

Comment: Couple of observations. You don't really need braces after `\item` around the item. I guess you can have them if you want, but I don't think they'd do anything. If you want just a space in math mode, ``\ `` is a much better way of getting it than `\text{ }` and you have an `array` with columns specified `cll`, but then you don't put in any `&`s so the result is just the one centred column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I minimised and completed your example with a dummy environment.

```
c_1<t< c_2
```

cannot be set in text mode. It needs to be in maths mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newenvironment{definition}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[Two-dimensional curves]
  {It is called a simple arc of a curve, the set $C$ of points $M(x,y) \in \R ^2 $
    (two-dimensional Euclidean space) satisfying one of the following equivalent equations;}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{
      $ y=f(x), \text{ where } a,b \in \R \text{ and are also fixed} \text{,}$
    }
    \item{
      $ F(x,y)=0, \text{ } a_1 \leq x \leq a_2,\text{ }b_1 \leq y \leq b_2 \text{ where, } a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \R \text{,}$
    }
    \item{
      $
      \left\{\begin{array}{cll}
        x=g(t)\\
        y=h(t)
      \end{array}\right. \text{, where }c_1<t< c_2 \text{ and } c_1,c_2 \in \R
      \text{.}$
    }
  \end{itemize}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You fail to note the big number of infelicities in the code.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I only fixed the error, it is true. Well, I also turned the original code into a minimal example. The empty definition of the environment was just to get past the error complaining it was undefined. The original loaded `amsthm` but didn't define `definition`. I figured the OP could easily restore their original definition, whereas I could not easily add it. (I never use `amsthm` myself.)

Comment: It's not only the missing code for `definition`: something like `\item{$ y=f(x), \text{ where } a,b \in \R \text{ and are also fixed} \text{,}$}` is utterly wrong.

Comment: @egreg - Would you say my code -- `\item $y=f(x)$, where $a,b\in\R$ and are also fixed` -- is acceptable? :-)

Comment: @Mico Of course! Although ungrammatical, but that's a problem with the original text.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. :-) The (English) grammar of that sentence can definitely stand some improving...

Comment: @egreg I would change it if Mico hadn't answered, but it does not seem right to do so now. Really, once I'd turned it into an MWE, I just focused on making it compile and didn't bother tidying it up. And although I wouldn't write this, I don't typeset enough maths to really know whether something is wrong or just clumsy or just not the way I'd do it. (I realised about the `\item{}`, obviously, but that isn't exactly wrong - the `{}` won't hurt anything, will it? Or will it?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to fixing the immediate issue related to not using math mode for math material (as in @cfr's answer), you should also (a) omit the unnecessary instances of `{` and `}` for grouping purposes -- in particular, `\item` does *not* take an argument that needs to be enclosed in curly braces --, (b) be more purposeful about using text and math mode -- all those `\text` statements are actually a sign of code confusion -- and (c) be more circumspect about defining an environment called `definition`; I suggest you load the `amsthm` package and use a `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}` directive.

[image]

Finally, I can't help but comment that there seems to be something missing in two of the three bullet point items: How do `a`, `b`, `c_1`, and `c_2` come into play?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[Two-dimensional curves]
The simple arc of a curve is the set $C$ of points $M(x,y)\in\R^2$ 
(two-dimensional Euclidean space) that satisfy one of the 
following equivalent equations:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $y=f(x)$, where $a,b\in\R$ and are also fixed,
    \item $F(x,y)=0$, $a_1 \leq x \leq a_2,$ $b_1 \leq y \leq b_2$, 
      where $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \R$,
    \item $\begin{cases} x=g(t)\\ y=h(t) \end{cases}$ 
      where $c_1<t<c_2$ and $c_1,c_2\in\R$.
  \end{itemize}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```